# Membership of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am a student of linguistics, not a mathematician. I am trying to account for some linguistic expressions with the set theoretical terminology and hence I am trying to learn the basic membership rules for sets. This is the problem with which I am struggling -

If $x$ is a member of set $y$, where $y$ is a set of cats $x$ is necessarily a cat.

$\therefore$ An expression like $a$ $cat$ will refer to a noun which is a member of set $C$ i.e. set of all cats.

Now what about an expression like $a$ $black$ $cat$? Obviously we know that black is an adjective here, but what is it's membership? If we say set $C$ has a subset $B$ which includes all the black cats, it will violate the first condition because we have defined set $C$ as a set of **cats**, but set $B$ is not a **cat**. How to account for $black$ in this model?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking.  Why can't we speak of a subset of a set?

Comment: As assumed in the question C is a set of cats. How can we have a set of black cats (which is not a **cat**) in the set of cats?

Comment: Because sets can have subsets.

Comment: An expression like "a cat" will refer to an object which is a member of set $C$ of all cats.

Comment: We have the set $C$ of all *cats* and the set $B$ of all *black things*. And we have the set $BC= B \cap C$ of all black cats. where $B \cap C$ is the *intersection* of the two sets, i.e. the set of all and only those objects that are in both sets.

Comment: We have that $BC \subseteq B$ and $BC \subseteq C$.

Comment: @lulu if I have had a set X which is a set of sets of cats then it could have contained subset as the definition says it is set of sets and our element is also a set, here our definition is set of **cats** and you are claiming that it can have a **set** of black cats. How is it possible?

Comment: You are conflating the **basic** distinction between *element* of a set and *subset* of a set: they are **not** the same concept.

Comment: Yes the answer to this question also suggests the same point. My bad. Can you suggest me a reading on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ is a subset of $C$, but that does not imply that $B$ must be a *member* of $C$. Being a subset and being a member are distinct properties. All we require for $B$ to be a subset of $C$ is that every element $b$ that is a member of $B$ is also a member of $C$. This is true because every black cat is also a cat.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know this. Can you suggest me a reading for the following statement? >Being a subset and being a member are distinct properties.< I want to read more on this.

Comment: @Niranjan To grasp basic concepts like set, member and subset I suggest you start with the Wikipedia articles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset.